# Why can I not assign a value to a gradle property in an extension?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am creating a custom gradle plugin in gradle 5.4. I have an extension:

```
public class ExternalResourcesPluginExtension {

    public final Property<Boolean> update;

    public ExternalResourcesPluginExtension(final Project project) {
        this.project = project;
        update = project.getObjects().property(Boolean.class).convention(false);
    }
}
```

Which I apply to the plugin:

```
final ExternalResourcesPluginExtension extension = project.getExtensions()
        .create(EXTENSION_NAME, ExternalResourcesPluginExtension.class, project);
```

But then when I try and assign to it like in all the examples:

```
externalResources {
    update = false
}
```

Then it fails with:

> Cannot cast object 'false' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class
>   'org.gradle.api.provider.Property'

If I change it to:

```
externalResources {
    update.set(false)
}
```

Then it works fine.

What is going on? Why can I not assign to my property like in the examples?

Comment: You have declare `update` field with type `Property<Boolean>` (and not Boolean directly) , that's why you cannot assign a Boolean value to this field directry (class cast exception) : you need to use the methods exposed by `Property` interface (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Property.html ) , e.g. `update.set(false)`

Comment: could you provide a link to examples from Gradle docs, where a value is assigned to a `Property` without using the dedicated setter method?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti See [Lazy Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#lazy_configuration) where it states "Note that an assignment statement can be used instead of calling Property.set()".

Comment: OK i missed that point in the documentation, but see the note at the end of this "Lazy configuration" chapter: `Note that Gradle Groovy DSL will generate setter methods for each Property-typed property in a task implementation. These setter methods allow you to configure the property using the assignment (=) operator as a convenience.` => it seems that the use of assignment = operator is made available only in Task's implementation. I guess that this convenient setter methods are not generated for Extension implementation.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Right so I guess the documentation is wrong then? The second example configures `greeting` on the `messages` extension. If you make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Comment: In fact my previous comment was wrong, the second example from the documentation is working fine too: the only difference is that in your case , you declared the property `update` as `public` and for some reason this makes the groovy property syntax ( `update = false` ) fail.. just try to remove the `public` modifier and it should work

Comment: related issue posted on Gradle forum : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/groovy-dsl-does-not-generate-setter-for-property-typed-properties/28650